# Where does TEMP environment variable value comes from?

Tags: windows, environment-variables

I'm trying to understand why I see different values for the `TEMP` environment variable.

This is how it looks in the Environment Variables window:

[image]

And here's what I get when I echo it in the cmd - note the `3` at the end:

[image]

Why is there a difference between the two (window vs. cmd), and how can I get to the place that the latter is defined at and change it?

This is unrelated to closing-then-opening the cmd; the echoed value persists.

Note: I have Admin privilege on my machine, and FWIW, I'm on Windows Server 2019.

Comment: You can assign the temporary directory to whatever directory you want. I am confused by what your question is exactly

Comment: Your system TEMP is not being used here.  Only your USER temp is being used.  The `3` makes no sense based on your other screen shot.  Open the registry editor and look at `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment`.  You will see where the value comes from there.  Look under `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment` for the system one.

Comment: @Ramhound I know I can set it to whatever I want, I'm just trying to understand why there's a discrepancy

Comment: You are comparing two different system variables, one is a system variable the other is a user variable, hence the discrepancy

Comment: @Ramhound, in my first image, the upper variable is the user variable, right? and the bottom variable is the system variable, right? and no `3` in niether of them. Then where's that `3` comes in my second image, of the cmd?

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas no `3` there too

Comment: check `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun` and `    HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun` to see if anyone changes the variable

Comment: @phuclv just checked. For the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` path, there's no `AutoRun` value, and for the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`, there's not even `Command Processor`.

Comment: Perhaps it has something to do with running SERVER?  What if you have more than one person logging in to the server with the same account?  I believe that is supported.. I am (of course) guessing but the '3' is indeed odd.

Comment: @HeyJude - You are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evaluating this variable on your Windows desktop PC e.g. in Windows 10 will likely not result in a number at the end, whereas doing the same on a remote desktop server, or possibly any Windows server, you will see the number appear (3 in your example).

It turns out there are a number of places these variables can be set:

- System level - server/PC default
- User level - overrides the above for a user
- Process level - overrides the above for a single process (more common for Linux, but apparently possible in Windows too)

Less well-known are "volatile variables" which are configured in the registry at "HKCU\VolatileEnvironment". It seems that this results in a number being appended which relates to the number of your session, but which surprisingly differs from the session number against your account in task manager. The idea is apparently so that you can have multiple sessions on a single host without your temp locations clashing. You can turn off this dynamic temp folder setting with this group policy setting:

- Windows Components/Remote Desktop Services/Remote Desktop Session Host/Temporary folders

Credit for this information to [Rakhesh.com](https://rakhesh.com/windows/temp-environment-variable-has-a-2-or-other-number-after-it/)

Answer (score 0):

The things you see in the System Properties window, and the Registry are not really environment variables, they are templates for the creation of each process's environment, which is in memory only. Command prompt will show whatever is currently in that specific instance of the cmd.exe process, which may or may not jibe with what other processes or the registry might have. Evidently something is, or has, modified the environment variables of the command prompt process you are showing.